# Looping through a nested python dictionary with key references

Tags: key-value

I have a dictionary which looks something like this-

```
{
'a': ['1','2','3','d'],
'b': ['x','y','z'],
'c': ['a','10'],
'd': ['x','5'],
'e': ['6'],
'y': ['11','12']
'x': ['0']
'z': ['a']
}
```

I am trying to resolve all the key references inside the list associated with key. So the final output should look like the following:

```
{
'a': ['1','2','3','0','5'],
'b': ['0','11','12','1','1','2','3','0','5'],
'c': ['1','2','3','0','5','10'],
'd': ['0','5'],
'e': ['6'],
'y': ['11','12']
'x': ['0']
'z' :['1','2','3','0','5']
}
```

I am trying to come up with a way where I can either rewrite the original dictionary with the resolved value or create a new dictionary with the resolved values.

Comment: Are recursive references possible, e.g. what is the expected result for `{'a': [1, 2, 'b'], 'b': [3, 4, 'c'], 'c': [5, 6]}`?  Also: What happens with `{'a': [1, 2, 'b'], 'b': [3, 4, 'a']}`?

Comment: For recursive references like you stated in the example - {'a': [1, 2, 'b'], 'b': [3, 4, 'c'], 'c': [5, 6]}. The expected output is - {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'b': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'c': [5, 6]}

The order in the values is really not important as long as all the nested keys are resolved. 

With the example {'a': [1, 2, 'b'], 'b': [3, 4, 'a']} 
the expected output would be {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [3, 4, 1, 2]}

Comment: Well, since you allow for and want to expand referential cycles, my second example has no finite solution. So you now need a definition on how and when to break the reference cycle. You might want to think this through again. You need an acyclic reference graph for the expansion to work.

Comment: Well the dictionary that does not contain anything with infinite solutions. It's pretty well defined like the example I have provided and the first example that you sited. The second example is currently not in the scope of the work I am doing.